# Finding a tangent line parallel to the x-axis with dy/dx

Tags: implicit-differentiation

1. $x^2+xy+y^2=7$
2. Find $dy/dx$
3. $dy/dx= (-2x-y)/(x+2y)$

How do I take $dy/dx$ and get the equation of the tangent line parallel to the $x$-axis?

Comment: What's your question, specifically?

Comment: Combine (1) with $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ from (3). If you have done it correctly, you get two lines, since (1) gives an ellipse centered at the origin.

Comment: The question is "what is the equation of the tangent line of  x^2+xy+y^2=7 parallel to the x-axis?"

Comment: The tangent line occurs when $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x)=0$. As Will pointed out you have everything needed to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$
x^2 + xy + y^2 = 7.
$$

Using implicit differentiation you get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} x^2 + xy + y^2 &= \frac{d}{dx} 7 &\Rightarrow\\
2x + y + x\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y\frac{dy}{dx} &= 0.
\end{align}
$$

From this you solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You get [you can do this]
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x-y}{x + 2y}
$$
To find the equation of the tangent line that is parallel to the $x$-axis, you need to determine the $x$ and $y$ such that the numerator is zero and the denominator is not zero. At those points you have a slope of zero. Then you can simply write down the equaltion of the tangent line (the slope is obviously zero, so...).

Comment: is the answer y=sqrt(7)?

Comment: @Paul / Matt: So if $y = -2x$ then from the original equation you have $3x^2 = 7$, so ...

Comment: A small matter of my idiosyncratic preference. From $2x+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, I would *immediately* set $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, getting $2x+y=0$. Division makes me nervous.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: That would be much better!